# Subset sum approach for natural numbers

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, subset-sum

There is an array of n elements where any element is a natural number. To find a sum if present in the array without duplication while adding

Approach

1. Remove all elements greater than the sum
2. Sort the array in descending order
3. Setting currentsum to 0
4. Loop i where i = first element of array through last
5. If currentsum + i <= sum then currentsum += i
6. If currentsum == sum then print true
7. Else print false

Is there any issues in this approach or is there test case that can give wrong answers.

Comment: Ok. Where is the code?

Comment: "Is there any issues" yes, lots. Basically it won't work.

Comment: "is there test case that can give wrong answers" yes, the smallest case has 3 elements in the set and involves numbers 1, 2, and/or 3. Good luck.

Comment: What you have come up with here is a so called greedy algorithm. For this problem it does not always give the correct result.

Comment: Did you try to click on the "subset-sum" tag you added? Lots of interesting stuff there.

Comment: you are just checking consecutives.

Comment: @n.m. Just out of curiosity: What is the instance you have in mind? I somehow fail to find it.

Comment: @Codor 3,2,2, sum to find is 4

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm presented in the question does not alyways yield the correct result. Consider an instance consisting of the values

```
7, 5, 3
```

which are already sorted in a decreasing manner. Let

```
8
```

be the target value for the sum. The algorithm in the question would select `7` as it is not larger that `8`, however adding `5` and `3` is not possible as the target value `8` would be exceeded. Finally, the algorithm would output `false`. On the other hand, selection of `5` and `3` would yield a sum value of `8`, which means that the output of the algorithm is wrong.